# Add a system maven dependency with a url instead of a file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I need to depend on a jar which isn't in any maven repo.  I currently just have a system dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nexua</groupId>
    <artifactId>register</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/register.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

is there some way I can have the file link to a url instead of a local file so it will stay up to date?As it stands I'll have to replace the file manually when I want it updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are best off using the internal (local) repository.  This is described in more detail at [«Introduction to Repositories»](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html).  Basically, you just copy your artifact into the proper directory with the proper filename (following Maven conventions) underneath this internal repository, and Maven will pick it up without needing to use `<systemPath>`.

This will require you to replace the file manually when it gets updated.  (Actually, to do it properly, it will require you to include the new version with a separate version suffix in the internal repository, and to update the `<version/>` in your `pom.xml`.)  The only better way around this is to have someone else manage the dependency - either in the Maven central repository, or another repository location that you reference from your `pom.xml`.  (In fact, you can setup your own - either for yourself or your workgroup, which I'd recommend.)

Comment: Reading this answer, I might assume a URL can't be used instead of a Path. Does anyone know if this is true?